# Resize canvas on page load

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am using the following snippet to resize a canvas element successfully. I need it to resize a canvas element *on page load* and not require user interaction to fire the `windowResize()` function.

```
(function($){
    $(window).resize(function(){
      windowResize();                      
    });         
})(jQuery);

function windowResize(){
   stage.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
   stage.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;    
   var test = (window.innerHeight/500)*1;
   exportRoot.scaleX = exportRoot.scaleY = test;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify your snippet to:

```
$(window).on('resize load', windowResize);
```

This will invoke `windowResize()` at both load and resize.

Answer (score 1):

Just call windowResize in jQuery-loaded.

```
$(function(){

    function windowResize(){
       stage.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
       stage.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;    
       var test = (window.innerHeight/500)*1;
       exportRoot.scaleX = exportRoot.scaleY = test;
    }

    ....

    $(window).resize(function(){ windowResize(); }); 

    windowResize();


}); // end $(function(){});
```

Comment: BOTH of these solutions worked for me. The first one is just a tad shorter in lines of code so I used that one but both are valid. Thank you both for the quick response and much needed help!